# Using a cookie as a variable in a Switch statement in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, wampserver

This snippet of code is suppose to compare the value of the `$_COOKIE` variable and move forward accordingly but instead I am getting the error

> Undefined index = type

Here is the code -

```
if ($result != false) {
$session_data = array(
'username' => $result[0]->username, //THIS WAS PREVIOUSLY user_name
'password' => $result[0]->password,
'type' => $result[0]->type,
);
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);


if (in_array($_COOKIE['type'], array("Admin", "User", "Library")))
switch ($_COOKIE['type']) {
case "Admin":
$this->load->view('admin_page');
break;

case "User":
$this->load->view('viewtry');
break;

case "Library":
    echo "yes";
    break;
default:
    echo "no";
}
```

****UPDATE****

I solved my problem, what I did was just replaced the two instances of `$_COOKIE['type']` with simply the variable `$type` as I declared it earlier. Kinda stupid of me to overlook that.

Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: There is no value set on $_COOKIE['type'] ...

Comment: what is `$result` values and how you getting those ??

Comment: Should you not be using the `Cookie Helper` to access cookies or `$this->input->cookie()` [The Manual page](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html)

Comment: Guys! I solved my problem, what I did was just replaced the two instances of $_COOKIE['type'] with simply the variable $type as i declared it earlier. Kinda stupid of me to overlook that, wasted 4 or so hours on this lol.

Comment: You cannot close your problem by writing "solved". You should either accept one of the answers or post your own answer an then accept it. This is how questions are marked as completed on Stack Overflow. You will get points if you do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$COOKIE` doesn't have `type` key. So, before get value of the `type`, you should check that the `type` was defined or not. You can use the function that is called `isset` for checking key.

```
if ($result != false) {
$session_data = array(
'username' => $result[0]->username, //THIS WAS PREVIOUSLY user_name
'password' => $result[0]->password,
'type' => $result[0]->type,
);
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);


if (isset($_COOKIE['type']) && in_array($_COOKIE['type'], array("Admin", "User", "Library")))
switch ($_COOKIE['type']) {
case "Admin":
$this->load->view('admin_page');
break;

case "User":
$this->load->view('viewtry');
break;

case "Library":
    echo "yes";
    break;
default:
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer. Try to explain your thoughts so that we can understand what you have done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid having your `switch` logic inside an `if` block. Instead consider something like:

```
$user_type = 
    (in_array($_COOKIE['type'], array("Admin", "User", "Library"))) 
    ? $_COOKIE['type'] 
    : NULL;

switch ($user_type) {
    case "Admin":
        $this->load->view('admin_page');
    break;

    case "User":
        $this->load->view('viewtry');
    break;

    case "Library":
        echo "yes";
    break;

    default:
        echo "no";
}
```

This way, `$user_type` gets set to `NULL` if `$_COOKIE['type']` isn't passed into the request, so it will be handled as the `default` in your `switch`.